# Domain Label contains illegal character ':'

Tags: c#, xml, sharp.xmpp

I am using `Sharp.XMPP` library for `FCM`. I can connect fine and it receives Upstream messages without issues. However, sending `ack` back to server has a response of Error Code 400 with following details

```
<JIDMalformed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" />
<text>"Malformed JID 'XXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXX_XXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX': domain label contains illegal character ':'"</text>
```

whereas the Xs replace the device registration token from which the Upstream message was received.
The code I'm using to form a message and send:

```
Sharp.Xmpp.Im.Message x = new Sharp.Xmpp.Im.Message(vFrom);
x.Data.SetAttribute("message_id", vMessageID);
x.Data.SetAttribute("message_type", "ack");
cl.SendMessage(x);
```

The string `vFrom` contains the device_token. I can not replace `:` as it is an essential part of device token and `\:` does not escape it either. What is the correct way of using colon in `XML` formats?

Comment: A colon is not a special character in xml.  See wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: I know it's not but the error is there. How do I solve it?

Comment: I think it is the single quote (apos) U+0027.  See wiki

Comment: A colon would be U+003A.  Try : "urnU+003AietfU+003AparamsU+003AxmlU+003AnsU+003Axmpp-stanzas"

Comment: The value of deviceID is from string variable `vFrom` and I have checked it with `console.write` and Text Visualizer of Visual Studio; the single quote appearing is in error description from server response message and not in the said variable.

Comment: I replaced ':' with 'U+003A' and it gives me the same error but now at '+'. I have also tried hexadecimal code '&#58;' and that's an error at '&'

Comment: A domain is a URL.  So the Sharp.XMPP is saying the xmlns is not a valid URL.  Try : <JIDMalformed xmlns:urn="xmpp-stanzas" xmlns:ietf="xmpp-stanzas" xmlns:params="xmpp-stanzas" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"  xmlns:ns="xmpp-stanzas" />  XML URL is reserved and must be the one in my code.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream#sending_an_ack_message is my format. The error is at 'to' which is pre-defined by firebase itself.

Comment: The xml standard allows different options.  I looks like sharp doesn't implement all the options.  I would first just eliminate the XML prefix.  If that doesn't work then go with the standard xmlns format.

Comment: Make sure for c# you follow the instructions on following webpage : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data

Comment: I guess it's the library, I'm checked with everything else for a long time now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you've added Attributes to `<data>` tag whereupon they should be Elements to `<gcm>`

```
var msg = Xml.Element("message");
var elem = Xml.Element("gcm" ,"google:mobile:data"); //the gcm tag with xmlns attribute
Xml.Child(msg, elem); //assign child to message tag
var data = new {to = vFrom; message_id = vMessageID, message_type = "ack"};
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
elem.Text(serializer.Serialize(data)); //not adding attributes
cl.SendMessage(new Sharp.Xmpp.Im.Message(new Sharp.Xmpp.Core.Message(data: elem)));
```

This [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gaox07t0ll6ms74/Sharp.Xmpp.rar?dl=0) is an improved version of Sharp.XMPP for FCM. It includes the class `Sharp.Xmpp.Core.Message` that is probably not committed to github. [This](https://github.com/pgstath/Sharp.Xmpp/issues/13) might help clarify.